# AngularJS Promise is not being cancelled when timeout called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, timeout

I am trying to implement a simple timeout functionality to my promise. Goal is if I do not receive response say in 1 second, then the request should be cancelled i.e. code should not wait for the response neither should the code after success be called. This seemed to me very simple code but I don't know why its not working. Following is my code:

```
var canceler = $q.defer();
var timeoutPromise = $timeout(function() {
    canceler.resolve(); //abort the request when timed out
    console.log("Timed out");
    }, 1000);
$http.put(PutUrl, PurDataObject, {timeout: canceler.promise})
  .then(function(response){
        // control should never come here if the response took longer than 1 second
});
```

Any help is appreciated. I am using AngularJS v1.5.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use `$q.defer()` as the `$timeout` service already returns a promise:

```
var timeoutPromise = $timeout(function() {
    console.log("Timed out");
    return "Timed out";
}, 1000);

$http.put(PutUrl, PurDataObject, {timeout: timeoutPromise})
  .then(function(response){
        // control should never come here if the response took longer than 1 second
});
```